# Trouble subtracting day from date in Sheets Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have written the following code and cannot figure out why it is not working in my Google Sheet:

```
function WEEKOF(myDay, myDate) {
  var wkDate = new Date(myDate);
  var StartDate = new Date();
  StartDate.setDate(wkDate.getDate()-myDay);
  return StartDate;
}
```

=WEEKOF(Weekday(A1), A1)

Cell A1 contains: 05/01/2016

Return: 7/26/2017

I'm expecting the return to be: 04/29/2016

Comment: I have no idea what date object is being used here, but are you sure you can just naively subtract things from Date objects like this? Day-date calculations are extremely tricky to get right, because dates are not numbers. They aren't even strict modulo values.

Comment: Well, clearly this is not the case. This looks _exactly_ like the sorts of problems one gets when they run up against the fact that dates, even epoch dates, don't play well with naive math.

Comment: Well, you are getting unexpected values from what _appears_ to be a simple subtraction of values that are intended to be turned into dates. As in, this is the central question you pose. It is a truism in development that many  people have run into subtle problems with day-date stuff that is just supposed to work.

Comment: Anyway, my advice is to read the Sheets API docs like the devil reads the bible, and assume that any "simple" math around dates, even epoch dates, can go horrifically wrong. I have no idea what the limitations of Sheets date APIs are, but every system and platform has its own strange day-date behaviour. See Java's several kicks at this can, for example.

Answer (score 1):

## Difference in Days,Hours,Minutes and Seconds

```
var adayinmilliseconds=24*60*60*1000;
var differenceBetweenTwoDatesInDays = Math.floor((date1.valueOf()-date2.valueOf())/adayinmilliseconds);
```

A Date Difference Function that output days, hours, minute and seconds.  From the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) Date objects are based on a time value that is the number of milliseconds since 1 January, 1970 UTC. The method of time() and valuOf() both provide us the the primitive value of dates ie the number of milliseconds from some date in the past.  Yes, it can be quite a large number but in the end with a little simple arithmetic Math.floor(), /, % you end up with an easy calculation. You can change the output to an array or an object depending upon your requirements.

```
function calcTimeDifference(Start,End)
{
  if(Start && End)
  {
    var second=1000;
    var minute=60*second;
    var hour=minute*60;
    var day=hour*24;
    var t1=new Date(Start).valueOf();
    var t2=new Date(End).valueOf();
    var d=t2-t1;
    var days=Math.floor(d/day);
    var hours=Math.floor(d%day/hour);
    var minutes=Math.floor(d%day%hour/minute);
    var seconds=Math.floor(d%day%hour%minute/second);
    return 'dd:hh:mm:ss\n' + days + ':' + hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;  
  }
  else
  {
    return 'Invalid Inputs';
  }
}
```

Comment: I'll defer to you, but the OP is already using the Sheets API for their own function.

Comment: It's a common initialism on SO. (I think part of your comment got elided. I *wonder* what it was.)